# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null Json data

Tags: javascript, json

The code below gives an error and displays only one value.

```
<h4>Recent Trades</h4>

    <div id="recenttrades0">
    <div id="recenttrades1">
    <div id="recenttrades2">
    <div id="recenttrades3">
    <div id="recenttrades4">
    <div id="recenttrades5">
    <div id="recenttrades6">
    <div id="recenttrades7">
    <div id="recenttrades8">
    <div id="recenttrades9">
    <div id="recenttrades10">
    <div id="recenttrades11">
    <div id="recenttrades12">
    <div id="recenttrades13">
    <div id="recenttrades14">
    <div id="recenttrades15">
    <div id="recenttrades16">
    <div id="recenttrades17">
    <div id="recenttrades18">
    <div id="recenttrades19">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/MSFT/book',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
      document.getElementById("recenttrades0").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['0'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['0'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades1").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['1'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['1'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades2").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['2'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['2'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades3").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['3'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['3'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades4").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['4'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['4'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades5").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['5'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['5'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades6").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['6'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['6'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades7").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['7'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['7'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades8").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['8'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['8'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades9").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['9'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['9'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades10").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['10'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['10'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades11").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['11'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['11'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades12").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['12'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['12'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades13").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['13'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['13'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades14").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['14'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['14'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades15").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['15'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['15'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades16").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['16'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['16'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades17").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['17'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['17'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades18").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['18'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['18'].size;
      document.getElementById("recenttrades19").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['19'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['19'].size;

    }
    });
}, 10000);

</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The code I have provided displays the first value in the div `document.getElementById("recenttrades0").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['0'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['0'].size;`

But, only displays one value in the DIV. I'm trying to display the price and order size, but I am encountering an error. Thank you for your help!

Comment: after running  your first line document.getElementById("recenttrades0").innerHTML = " Price: " + data.trades['0'].price + " Size: " + data.trades['0'].size;
 the all div except "recenttrades0" was removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is displaying one value in a `div` because in your code the `div` are nested so when you are setting `.innerHTML` of `recenttrades0` it is removing all the other divs.

```
<!-- Nested divs -->
<div>
   <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You do not need to hardcode all these and generate them dynamically.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/MSFT/book',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    var _html = "";
    data.trades.forEach(function(el){
       // Build div dynamically here
       _html += "<div> Price: " + el.price + " Size: " + el.size+"</div>";
    });
    // Append all the HTML to #main_container
    $("#main_container").html(_html);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Recent Trades</h4>
<div id="main_container">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: Displays only one still. I need all 20. Thanks tho for your help!

Comment: Oh, weird. I must be doing something wrong on my end. Thank you void!

Comment: Wow, you saved me a lot of time void. Thanks, this works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try The below code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
             $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/MSFT/book',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'get',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data.trades);
                    data.trades.forEach(function(val)
                    {
                        console.log(val);
                        $('#row').append('<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-3">'+val.price+'</div><div class="col-sm-3">'+val.size+'</div></div>');
                    })
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Recent Trades</h4>
    <div id="row">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The append() method inserts specified content at the end of the selected elements. here selected element is your div tag with unique id. And if you like the the answer upvote it.

Comment: Not, exactly. What I am looking for, I'd like all recent trades to refresh in a div and there are 20. Thanks tho for your help.